# statistics sample mean and population mean

Tags: statistics

I have this assignment which requires having a sample of 20 houses in my area and comparing their prices to a study that was made, and then making null and alternate hypothesis. 
One of the questions is asking to describe mathematically the sample mean compared to the population mean. what do they mean by that as I only know that the sample mean is usually included in the population mean? and how to describe it mathematically?
 thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I am having trouble making this Comment print clearly in a 'comment box', so I'm trying it as an Answer.

I suppose you are expected to view the 'study' as authoritative and use its mean as 'population' mean $\mu$. The mean from your small sample of 20 would be the sample mean $\bar X.$

If there is also a 'population' variance $\sigma$ in the study, then *maybe* you are expected to start with $Z = \frac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{20}},$ assuming it is approximately standard normal. In that case you might be able to test the null hypothesis that your sample
is taken properly from the houses in the study, rejecting at the 5% level if $|Z| > 1.96.$

If there is no SD given in the paper, then
maybe you are expected to use $T = \frac{\bar X - \mu}{S/\sqrt{20}},$ where
$S$ is the sample SD of your sample of 20. Then you would assume that $T$ has Student's t distribution with 19 degrees of freedom, get the critical value 2.093 from a printed table, and reject the null hypothesis if $|T| > 2.093.$

Your description of your assignment is a bit vague, so all of this can only be regarded as guesses.